# Calling an arrow function from another arrow function inside object literal notation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to use object literal notation to generate a namespace:

```
const featureGoogleAnalytics = {
  gTagId: 'G-XXXXXXX', // Your Google Analytics ID

...

  resetConsent: () => { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    localStorage.removeItem('googleAnalyticsConsent');
...
    return false;
  },


  /**
   * Initializes feature Google Analytics
   * Supposed to run after poageload, callback for $( () => { ... } );
   */
  init: () => { 
    this.resetConsent();
    ...
  },
};
```

Now the line

```
this.resetConsent();
```

Errors with

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.resetConsent is not a function
```

What did I miss? I assume the syntax of calling the `resetConsent` function is wrong, but I wasn't able to Google it.

Comment: The calling syntax is correct, but arrow functions don't bind `this`. If you want to access the object write a regular method.

Comment: You need to use traditional functions i.e. change `() =>` to `function()`.

Comment: Define the method like `init() { /* code */ }`, not using an arrow function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments, don't use an anonymous function wrapper in an Object definition.

```js
const featureGoogleAnalytics = {
  gTagId: 'G-XXXXXXX', // Your Google Analytics ID

...

  resetConsent: function() { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    localStorage.removeItem('googleAnalyticsConsent');
...
    return false;
  },


  /**
   * Initializes feature Google Analytics
   * Supposed to run after poageload, callback for $( () => { ... } );
   */
  init: function() { 
    this.resetConsent();
    ...
  },
};
```

Alternatively:

```js
const featureGoogleAnalytics = {
  gTagId: 'G-XXXXXXX', // Your Google Analytics ID

...

  resetConsent() { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    localStorage.removeItem('googleAnalyticsConsent');
...
    return false;
  },


  /**
   * Initializes feature Google Analytics
   * Supposed to run after poageload, callback for $( () => { ... } );
   */
  init() { 
    this.resetConsent();
    ...
  },
};
```